# How can I conditionally apply class, which has dynamic attribute, in classNames

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I have a simple `div` and want to add it a new class.
I have 2 attributes, one is a `boolean`, let's call it `myBoolean`, another is a number, I called it `myNumber`.

Here my code:

```
<div className={className}></div>
```

I want to add new class with condition if my first attribute is `true`.

Something like this:

```
<div className={`className ${myBoolean && "has-columns-${myNumber}"}`}></div>
```

How can I make it work?

Thanks.

Comment: You are so close! Try something like this: 

<div className={myBoolean && \`has-columns-${myNumber}\`}></div>

Comment: What about my className? Sorry, i'm a newbie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like

```html
<div className={`${className} ${myBoolean && `has-columns-${myNumber}`}`}></div>
```

Also you can try to use [classnames](https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames), a perfect helper for situations like yours:

1. Install `classnames`: `npm install classnames --save` or `yarn add classnames`
2. Use it like this:

```js
import cx from 'classnames';
// ...
<div className={cx(className, { `has-columns-${myNumber}`: myBoolean })}></div>
```

The point is that you can insert unlimited number of arguments to cx function which can be strings, objects with class names and booleans to specify whether it should be used or not. Then that function concatenates all of these class names and returns one big string which you use inside your components.

Comment: Check out ```classnames```if still not, this thing will really simplify your life, because such things with classes happen like almost every day :)

Comment: I will check it out. Thanks.